# Why are my textures not consistently drawing when I switch from Orthographic to Perspective?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

I'm relatively new to opengl and I'm trying to make a basic 2d scened with gl-4.5. I have three tiles laid next to each other on the plane, two images from a single spritesheet and a coloured rectangle. It works fine when I view it in orthographic. When I view it in perspective, the textures don't consistently draw as I move toward/away the plane upon which the quads are rendered. As in, sometimes the tiles show as expected and sometimes they show as white boxes.

Examples:

[Orthographic view, works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbbM.png)
[image]

[Perspective view, everything shows fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKoJE.png)
[image]

[Perspective view, slightly changed Z-coord for camera, images show up as white rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E93Zq.png)
[image]

The only thing that actually changes between the two views is here:

```
    glm::mat4 ViewProjection;
    if(!State->isPerspective)
    {
        // Orthographic Control
        const r32 cameraSpeed = 0.05f;
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveLeft))
        {
            State->LeftCoord -= cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveRight))
        {
            State->LeftCoord += cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveUp))
        {
            State->BottomCoord += cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveDown))
        {
            State->BottomCoord -= cameraSpeed;
        }
        
        State->Zoom += Input->Mouse.Wheel.y;
        
        r32 AspectRatio = static_cast<float>(ScreenWidth)/static_cast<float>(ScreenHeight);
        r32 ZoomLevel = (float)ScreenHeight/State->Zoom;
        State->RightCoord = State->LeftCoord + (AspectRatio*ZoomLevel);
        State->TopCoord = State->BottomCoord + ZoomLevel;
        ViewProjection = glm::ortho(State->LeftCoord, State->RightCoord, State->BottomCoord, State->TopCoord , -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        // Perspective Control
        const r32 cameraSpeed = 0.1f;
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveLeft))
        {
            State->cameraPos -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(State->cameraFront, State->cameraUp))*cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveRight))
        {
            State->cameraPos += glm::normalize(glm::cross(State->cameraFront, State->cameraUp))*cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveUp))
        {
            State->cameraPos += glm::normalize(State->cameraUp) * cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveDown))
        {
            State->cameraPos -= glm::normalize(State->cameraUp) * cameraSpeed;
        }
        
        State->cameraPos += Input->Mouse.Wheel.y * State->cameraFront * cameraSpeed;
        
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (r32)ScreenWidth/(r32)ScreenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(State->cameraPos, State->cameraPos + State->cameraFront, State->cameraUp);
        ViewProjection = projection*view;
    }
    
    int Loc = glGetUniformLocation(State->ShaderProgramId, "u_ViewProjection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(Loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewProjection[0][0]);
```

Here is the initialization code

```
    
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    
    // Create the vertex/fragment shaders, compile the program.
    {
        u32 VertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        {
            glShaderSource(VertexShaderId, 1, &BatchVertexShader, nullptr);
            glCompileShader(VertexShaderId);
            
            int Result;
            glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
            if(Result == GL_FALSE)
            {
                s32 Length;
                glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &Length);
                char *Message = (char*)alloca(Length * sizeof(char));
                glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderId, Length, &Length, Message);
                log_error("Failed to compile shader: {}", Message);
                
                free(Message);
                
                glDeleteShader(VertexShaderId);
            }
        }
        
        u32 FragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        {
            glShaderSource(FragmentShaderId, 1, &BatchFragmentShader, nullptr);
            glCompileShader(FragmentShaderId);
            
            int Result;
            glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
            if(Result == GL_FALSE)
            {
                s32 Length;
                glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &Length);
                char *Message = (char*)alloca(Length * sizeof(char));
                glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderId, Length, &Length, Message);
                log_error("Failed to compile shader: {}", Message);
                
                free(Message);
                
                glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderId);
            }
        }
        
        u32 ProgramId = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ProgramId, VertexShaderId);
        glAttachShader(ProgramId, FragmentShaderId);
        glLinkProgram(ProgramId);
        glValidateProgram(ProgramId);
        
        glDeleteShader(VertexShaderId);
        glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderId);
        
        State.ShaderProgramId = ProgramId;
    }
    glUseProgram(State.ShaderProgramId);
    
    // Setup the sampler2d array
    auto loc = glGetUniformLocation(State.ShaderProgramId, "u_Textures");
    int Samplers[NumTextureUnits];
    for(int i = 0; i< NumTextureUnits; ++i)
    {
        Samplers[i] = i;
    }
    glUniform1iv(loc, NumTextureUnits, Samplers);
    State.NumTextureUnits = NumTextureUnits;
    
    // Vertices, Indices, etc. Setup.
    u32 Indices[MaxIndices];
    u32 Offset = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MaxIndices; i += 6)
    {
        Indices[i+0] = Offset + 0;
        Indices[i+1] = Offset + 1;
        Indices[i+2] = Offset + 2;
        Indices[i+3] = Offset + 2;
        Indices[i+4] = Offset + 3;
        Indices[i+5] = Offset + 0;
        Offset += 4;
    };
    
    State.QuadPositions[0] = {-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    State.QuadPositions[1] = { 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    State.QuadPositions[2] = { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    State.QuadPositions[3] = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &State.QuadVao);
    glBindVertexArray(State.QuadVao);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &State.QuadVbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, State.QuadVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MaxVertices*sizeof(QuadVertex), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QuadVertex), (void*)offsetof(QuadVertex, Position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QuadVertex), (void*)offsetof(QuadVertex, Colour));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QuadVertex), (void*)offsetof(QuadVertex, TexCoords));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QuadVertex), (void*)offsetof(QuadVertex, TexId));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &State.QuadIbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, State.QuadIbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    
    /// Generate a white texture for drawing coloured quads.
    
    u32 WhiteTextureData = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    State.WhiteTexture = got_CreateTexture(true, {1,1}, 4, (u8*)&WhiteTextureData);
    State.CurrentBoundTextures[0] = State.WhiteTexture.Id;
```

Here is the update code:

```
    /// Start Update
    
    glViewport(0 ,0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(State->ShaderProgramId);
    
    ///  Bind the sprite sheet to the next texture slot, only once.
    if(State->SpritesheetTexture.ImageId == 0)
    {
        u32 SpritesheetTextureId;
        glGenTextures(1, &SpritesheetTextureId);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, SpritesheetTextureId);
        
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, SpritesheetImage->Dim.x, SpritesheetImage->Dim.y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, SpritesheetImage->Data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        
        State->SpritesheetTexture.Id = SpritesheetTextureId;
        State->SpritesheetTexture.ImageId = (int)enImageType::RpgSpritesheet;
        
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
    
    glBindTextureUnit(0, State->WhiteTexture.Id);
    glBindTextureUnit(1, State->SpritesheetTexture.Id);
    
    /// Camera Control / projection
    if(Is(Input->Keyboard.Action & enGameButton::Released))
    {
        State->isPerspective = !State->isPerspective;
    }
    
    glm::mat4 ViewProjection;
    if(!State->isPerspective)
    {
        // Orthographic Control
        const r32 cameraSpeed = 0.05f;
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveLeft))
        {
            State->LeftCoord -= cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveRight))
        {
            State->LeftCoord += cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveUp))
        {
            State->BottomCoord += cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveDown))
        {
            State->BottomCoord -= cameraSpeed;
        }
        
        State->Zoom += Input->Mouse.Wheel.y;
        
        r32 AspectRatio = static_cast<float>(ScreenWidth)/static_cast<float>(ScreenHeight);
        r32 ZoomLevel = (float)ScreenHeight/State->Zoom;
        State->RightCoord = State->LeftCoord + (AspectRatio*ZoomLevel);
        State->TopCoord = State->BottomCoord + ZoomLevel;
        ViewProjection = glm::ortho(State->LeftCoord, State->RightCoord, State->BottomCoord, State->TopCoord , -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        // Perspective Control
        const r32 cameraSpeed = 0.1f;
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveLeft))
        {
            State->cameraPos -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(State->cameraFront, State->cameraUp))*cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveRight))
        {
            State->cameraPos += glm::normalize(glm::cross(State->cameraFront, State->cameraUp))*cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveUp))
        {
            State->cameraPos += glm::normalize(State->cameraUp) * cameraSpeed;
        }
        if(Is(Input->Keyboard.MoveDown))
        {
            State->cameraPos -= glm::normalize(State->cameraUp) * cameraSpeed;
        }
        
        State->cameraPos += Input->Mouse.Wheel.y * State->cameraFront * cameraSpeed;
        
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (r32)ScreenWidth/(r32)ScreenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(State->cameraPos, State->cameraPos + State->cameraFront, State->cameraUp);
        ViewProjection = projection*view;
    }
    
    int Loc = glGetUniformLocation(State->ShaderProgramId, "u_ViewProjection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(Loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewProjection[0][0]);
    
    State->QuadDrawPtr = 0;
    State->QuadDrawIndexCount = 0;
    State->BoundTextureCount = 1;
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, State->QuadVbo);
    
    /// Render First Textured Quad.
    {
        render_image *Image = &RenderCommandList->CommandList[0].Image;
        res_image const *ImageProps = Image->Image;
        
        glBindTextureUnit(1, State->SpritesheetTexture.Id);
        u32 TexId = 1; // Sprite Sheet is is slot one of the 2dsample array.
        
        glm::vec3 Scale = glm::vec3(Image->Size.x/2.0f, Image->Size.y/2.0f, 1.0f);
        
        glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        Model = glm::translate(Model, {Image->CenterP.x, Image->CenterP.y, 0.0f});
        Model = glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(Image->Angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 
        Model = glm::translate(Model, {Image->Offset.x, Image->Offset.y, 0.0f});
        Model = glm::scale(Model, Scale);
        
        QuadVertex Vertex[4];
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            Vertex[j].Position = Model * State->QuadPositions[j];
            Vertex[j].Colour = glm::vec4(Image->Colour.r, Image->Colour.g, Image->Colour.b, Image->Colour.a);
            Vertex[j].TexCoords = {ImageProps->DrawArea[j].x, ImageProps->DrawArea[j].y};
            Vertex[j].TexId = (r32)TexId;
        }
        
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, State->QuadDrawPtr, 4*sizeof(QuadVertex), Vertex);
        
        State->QuadDrawPtr += 4*sizeof(QuadVertex);
        State->QuadDrawIndexCount += 6;
    }
    
    /// Render Second Textured Quad
    {
        render_image *Image = &RenderCommandList->CommandList[1].Image;
        res_image const *ImageProps = Image->Image;
        
        glBindTextureUnit(1, State->SpritesheetTexture.Id);
        u32 TexId = 1; // Sprite Sheet is is slot one of the 2dsample array.
        
        glm::vec3 Scale = glm::vec3(Image->Size.x/2.0f, Image->Size.y/2.0f, 1.0f);
        
        glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        Model = glm::translate(Model, {Image->CenterP.x, Image->CenterP.y, 0.0f});
        Model = glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(Image->Angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 
        Model = glm::translate(Model, {Image->Offset.x, Image->Offset.y, 0.0f});
        Model = glm::scale(Model, Scale);
        
        QuadVertex Vertex[4];
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            Vertex[j].Position = Model * State->QuadPositions[j];
            Vertex[j].Colour = glm::vec4(Image->Colour.r, Image->Colour.g, Image->Colour.b, Image->Colour.a);
            Vertex[j].TexCoords = {ImageProps->DrawArea[j].x, ImageProps->DrawArea[j].y};
            Vertex[j].TexId = (r32)TexId;
        }
        
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, State->QuadDrawPtr, 4*sizeof(QuadVertex), Vertex);
        
        State->QuadDrawPtr += 4*sizeof(QuadVertex);
        State->QuadDrawIndexCount += 6;
    }
    
    /// Render Coloured Quad
    {
        render_rectangle *Rectangle = &RenderCommandList->CommandList[2].Rectangle;
        r32 TexId = 0.0f; // By definition, this is the white pixel.
        
        glm::vec3 Scale = glm::vec3(Rectangle->Size.x/2.0f, Rectangle->Size.y/2.0f, 1.0f);
        
        glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        Model = glm::translate(Model, {Rectangle->CenterP.x, Rectangle->CenterP.y, 0.0f});
        Model = glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(Rectangle->Angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 
        Model = glm::translate(Model, {Rectangle->Offset.x, Rectangle->Offset.y, 0.0f});
        Model = glm::scale(Model, Scale);
        
        QuadVertex Vertex[4];
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            Vertex[j].Position = Model * State->QuadPositions[j];
            Vertex[j].Colour = glm::vec4(Rectangle->Colour.r, Rectangle->Colour.g, Rectangle->Colour.b, Rectangle->Colour.a);
            Vertex[j].TexCoords = State->TexCoords[j];
            Vertex[j].TexId = (r32)TexId;
        }
        
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, State->QuadDrawPtr, 4*sizeof(QuadVertex), Vertex);
        
        State->QuadDrawPtr += 4*sizeof(QuadVertex);
        State->QuadDrawIndexCount += 6;
    }
    
    glBindVertexArray(State->QuadVao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, State->QuadDrawIndexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    
}
```

The Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 a_Colour;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 a_TexCoords;
layout (location = 3) in float a_TexId;

out vec4 v_Colour;
out vec2 v_TexCoords;
out float v_TexId;

uniform mat4 u_ViewProjection;

void main()
{
    v_Colour = a_Colour;
    v_TexCoords = a_TexCoords;
    v_TexId = a_TexId;
    gl_Position = u_ViewProjection * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
}
```

The Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 v_Colour;
in vec2 v_TexCoords;
in float v_TexId;

out vec4 o_Colour;

uniform sampler2D u_Textures[32];

void main()
{ 
    int TexId = int(v_TexId);
    o_Colour = v_Colour * texture(u_Textures[TexId], v_TexCoords);
}
```

Why are my textures not consistently drawing?

Comment: Your code is not valid within the guarantees of the GLSL spec at all. Arrays of samplers must be indexed only by a dynamically uniform expression, otherwise the results will be undefined. And besides that, due to numeric inaccuracies in the perspective-corrected interpolation, the value you get as `TexId` in the shader might end up as off-by-one.

Comment: I'm attempting to use batch rendering, as described in a [yt series by the cherno](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98f5vZ8nJ6UengEkZUMC4fy5), which is where passing in the float comes from. Hard coding that to 1 in the fragment shader worked, so a rounding error is plausible. (Why you'd get a rounding error when passing in either 0.0f or 1.0f and there's no math involved is beyond me.) I tried to pass in an int for TexID, with both glVertexAttribIPointer and glVertexAttribPointer, which failed.

How should I specify which texture to use for a given quad?

Comment: "(Why you'd get a rounding error when passing in either 0.0f or 1.0f and there's no math involved is beyond me.)" In-between `out float foo` in the vertex shader and `in float foo` in the fragment shader, there is _lots_ of math involved, namely the whole perspective-corrected interpolation. Use  a `flat` qualifier if you don't want interpolation. But again, your shaders are way outside of what OpenGL spec guarantees to work, this is not the proper way to do batched rendering. Use texture arrays, not arrays of `sampler`s.

Comment: I changed out the float to an int and added the 'flat' qualifier (which was the piece I was missing before, it seems) and now it works as expected. I'll have to look into the texture arrays and how they work. Thanks for your assistance. If you have a good reference on batched rendering, I would be appreciative.